# Digital clock is not changing time

Tags: android

I am developing one Digital Clock Widget. I wrote the code. But it is not updating the time. I am not using any service and running in simulator. My code is like below:

```
     public class ExampleAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider 
{
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) 
    {
        final int NUM = appWidgetIds.length;
        for(int i =0; i<NUM; i++)
        {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
                RemoteViews remoteview = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget1);
//          remoteview.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pending);
            remoteview.setTextViewText(R.id.Time_text, df.format(new Date()));
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteview);
        }
    }
```

My widget_layout.xml is below:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/widgetstyle"
 >
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/Time_text" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
 />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone help??

Comment: What problem specifically does it show? is there any error log that can show you more specifically what didn't work?

Comment: No error is showing. Only when i am try to add that widget in the home screen, it is saying problem loading widget. For analog code, same sort of code is working.

Comment: Hey, that's interesting -- can you show the analog code that works?

Comment: Now my digital clock is working. But it is not changing the time. I edited the above code

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/app-widget-using-alarm-manager.html Here is an example enjoy it :). Thanks