# How can i create a Digital clock widget in Android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [error is showing for Digital Clock widget Application in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079853/error-is-showing-for-digital-clock-widget-application-in-android)

I want to develop one Digital Clock Widget for Home Screen in Android. I want some sample code. Can any one please help me??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a "give me the codes" sort of website. If you get stuck when programming your clock widget, feel free to come back with a specific question.

Comment: i already asked that kind of problem but no one answered. If you have any link or sample code please share it. Otherwise no need to inform me what is the principle of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ah. [Your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079853/error-is-showing-for-digital-clock-widget-application-in-android) was definitely better but the problem description ("doesn't load") is pretty vague. Make that more specific and perhaps someone will spot the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://buildmobile.com/how-to-code-an-android-widget/
check this link..this is the exact thing you wanted.refer to appwidgets in developers.android.com for more information regarding appwidgets
and do some google search before asking questions in community.

Comment: Hey i am running it in emulator. But time is not changing.